# PowerShell XML Parsing & Export

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I'm fairly new using PowerShell, and just joined stackoverflow.
I have a project at work to try to parse an XML file and export some specific nodes to a csv file. 
I need the `*<group>name"unique name"*` and the member task # exported from multiple entries in the file to be exported to the .csv.

The XML file looks like the below example with several entries for *Group Name & the associating task #:*

```xml
<settings><tasks><groups>
<Group Name="some name">
<Notes>Some notes here</Notes>
<Member t="task">159711687</Member>
<Member t="task">584643293</Member>
<Member t="task">465828474</Member>
<Member t="task">262255905</Member>
<Member t="task">121466829</Member>
<Member t="task">257067112</Member>
</Group>

<Group Name="some name 2">
<Notes>Testing</Notes>
<Member t="task">865485927</Member>
<Member t="task">363897901</Member>
<Member t="task">848275733</Member>
<Member t="task">471573148</Member>
<Member t="task">312701058</Member>
<Member t="task">667795378</Member>
<Member>160178363</Member>
<Member>149985003</Member>
</Group>
```

so far I've gotten

```
$xml = [xml] (gc "\\servername\path\to\file.xml")
$xml.settings.tasks.groups.group
```

I've also tried ***| select member -expandproperty member*** but it doesn't return the formatting correctly, and obviously that does not return the name either.

I've also tried a basic ***| format-list name, member***
 and format-table with little results also.

Any pointers in the right direction for this newbie would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're headed in the right direction.  You just need to remember that your element reference (second line in your code) actually returns an array of elements.  Once you have the array, you just need to traverse it like this:

```
[xml]$xml = gc .\groups.xml
$groups = $xml.settings.tasks.groups.Group  # $groups is an array of Group elements
foreach($i in $groups) {
    write-output $i.Name         # get the Name attribute for each Group element
    foreach($j in $i.Member) {   # $i.Member is an array of Member for each Group element
        write-output $j."#text"  # get the text contained in each Member element
    }
}
```